# I don't understand what 果てた mean?

Tags: meaning

「The Last of Us Part II」は感染症によってゾンビのような怪物になり果てた人間がはびこる、荒廃した世界を舞台としている。
From Jisho the word means completely, so does it mean in this passage that the people become completely zombies?

Comment: Your question says 「果した」 but the text says 「果てた」...

Comment: Whoops thanks you very much

Comment: You looked up 果てる, but not なり果てる, correct?

Comment: Correct, I did not, I don't even know why it is なり not なるor なって

Comment: Because it's part of one word. なりはてる.

Comment: Still can't find that word, do you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: You said you used Jisho, right? It's also on Jisho. https://jisho.org/word/%E6%88%90%E3%82%8A%E6%9E%9C%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more than two handfuls of V果てる compound verbs, though I'm hesitant to say that it is fully productive.

It adds a nuance "thoroughly and irreversibly" to the base verb (呆れ果てる, 消え果てる), and often carries a connotation of "ruined" (荒れ果てる, 朽ち果てる). Few instances actually translate into "wholly" in number (絶え果てる).

なり果てる is なる "turn into" + 果てる, which suggests that their humanity (or that like) has been perished. Incidentally we occasionally use 変わり果てる to describe a body of violent death.